# Layout for 2 columns in java

Tags: java, layout, scrollpane

I have a code in java:

```
gamePanel = new JPanel();
  gamePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  scrollPane = new JScrollPane(gamePanel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
     JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);   
  scrollPane.setBounds(5,50,300,100);

  JButton btn1 = new JButton("btn 1");
  JButton btn2 = new JButton("btn 2");
  JButton btn3 = new JButton("btn 3");
  JButton btn4 = new JButton("btn 4");
  JButton btn5 = new JButton("btn 5");
  gamePanel.add(btn1);
  gamePanel.add(btn2);
  gamePanel.add(btn3);
  gamePanel.add(btn4);
  gamePanel.add(btn5);
```

I want the outcome to be:

```
--------------------------
| Name1      |  Button 1 |
--------------------------
| Name2      |  Button 2 |
--------------------------
| Name3      |  Button 3 |
--------------------------
```

It must use the scrollpane if it exceeds the size of JPanel.

In my code the outcome is:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| Name1      |  Button 1 | Name2      |  Button 2 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: GridLayout, GridBagLayout or MigLayout, your pick.

Comment: If i use GridLayout, The Buttons are exactly in JPanel size. I need to make it scroll.

Comment: Then why not GridBagLayout -- what happens when you try this?

Comment: Don't do this: `scrollPane.setBounds(5,50,300,100);` since by doing this you're painting yourself into a corner.

Answer (score 0):

JPanels use a FlowLayout by default, so you don't need to declare it. Try with GridLayout, like this:

```
    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2,2,2));


    JButton btn1 = new JButton("btn 1");
    JLabel name1 = new JLabel("name1");
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("btn 2");
    JLabel name2 = new JLabel("name2");
    JButton btn3 = new JButton("btn 3");
    JLabel name3 = new JLabel("name3");

    gamePanel.add(name1);
    gamePanel.add(btn1);
    gamePanel.add(name2);
    gamePanel.add(btn2);
    gamePanel.add(name3);
    gamePanel.add(btn3);
```